# Resetting lost root-pwd on CentOS 8 just don't work

Tags: selinux, root, centos8

i just don't know. I have reset lost root-pwds on Linux boxes maybe 5 times a year in the 30 years experience as IT-Admin, but this time i#m just confused.
I just don't manage to login on my CentOS box.
I followed the common known path like described in e.g. https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/recover-root-passwd (also tried the other way with /bin/sh) but after rebooting i still cannot log in :-(

Someone has a idea what's the problem with my box (or with me? am i just to old now?  :-(
Somehow i think it's because of SeLinux. Cause always on CentOS when something seems just not to work it's because of SeLinux?

Pls give me a hint and a "Poor man" :-(

Comment: Please describe exactly what you did. Just pointing to a tutorial is not useful because we have no way of knowing which steps you took and which you inadvertently didn't. With the current information there is no way to answer your question, except that it's highly unlikely that SELinux is the cause.

Comment: A common problem is having a different keyboard layout in the rescue environment, so be careful with special chars in the password.

Answer (score 0):

here are a few things to try that may give clues to reasons you cannot log in ...
and i assume you are using console to login and not a remote login via network?

1. add a new user account (preferably with sudo privilege) and confirm if you can login?
2. login with new account and check shadow file to verify that your password change persists.
3. disable or put selinux in permissive mode to eliminate that possibility.